# How to pass an unknown class Type in ResponseEntity<>

Tags: java, generics

```
public void etisLogAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, EtisLog etisLog) throws Throwable {

        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
         MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getStaticPart().getSignature();
         Method method = methodSignature.getMethod();

         String[] paramNames =  ((MethodSignature) joinPoint
                    .getSignature()).getParameterNames();

         for(String paramName: paramNames) {
             logger.info("paramName:" +paramName);
         }


        try {

            Object result = joinPoint.proceed();

             if(methodSignature instanceof MethodSignature) {
                 final Class<?>[] parameterTypes = methodSignature.getParameterTypes();
                    for(final Class<?> pt : parameterTypes){
                        logger.info("Parameter type:" + pt);
                    }
             }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ResponseEntity<CaseOutlineHeader> returnValue = (ResponseEntity<CaseOutlineHeader>) result;




            result = etisLog.trasactionDetail().toString()+" "+returnValue.getBody().getCode().toString();



        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

The class `CaseOutlineHeader` is what I want to be changed. the `parameterTypes` variable contains the name of the class that I would like to pass inside the tag of the ResponseEntity<>. What if I would like to pass a different class Name. How should I do that to be flexible to accept the different class name?

If i do : `ResponseEntity<parameterTypes> returnValue = (ResponseEntity<parameterTypes>) result;`

it will say an error parameterTypes cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: how many values are expected in the array `parameterTypes `?

Comment: Do you have control over all the classes, like CaseOutlineHeader, which can be returned in the ResponseEntity? If that is the case I would implement an interface that they all implement, and put the methods that your AOP logic uses inside the interface.

Comment: Actually, you cannot provide variables as a generic types. Diamond quotes in ResponseEntity accepts only types.

Comment: Do you know in advance what is the wildcard class of parameter types variable?

Comment: @StackVictor only one value(1 class)

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek i dont get it, different classes implements there own interface. i annotate the methods inside the controller like this:
@EtisLog(module = "SYSAD", subModule = "MNGOutline", trasactionDetail = "Added case outline ")
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ResponseEntity<CaseOutlineHeader> save(@RequestBody CaseOutlineHeader mngCaseOutlines) {
  return new ResponseEntity<>(manageCaseOutlineService.save(mngCaseOutlines), HttpStatus.OK);
 } i have a controller ,service and repo

Comment: @K.Khanda i dont know how to implement wildcard on this

Comment: You can change the return type to ResponseEntity<?> which will allow you to return ResponseEntity with any generic Parameter.

Comment: @amRika where will i pass the parameterTypes variable?

Comment: You can't pass a type variable to an AOP method. You will have to case the result to something.  `ResponseEntity<MyInterface>` would work if all possible return values implemented MyInterface, and MyInterface defined the getCode() method.

Comment: @LogronJ see I have posted the code is that what u want or if it's not please explain ur requirement and the changes u want.

Comment: Your question is not really about Spring, AOP or AspectJ at all, it is about Java generics. Thus I have changed your question tags. And may I ask if you have ever read a tutorial on generics before trying to use them and even mix them with other technologies like Spring and AOP? I think you should do that because if you have problems you do not know where they come from anymore if you are a newbie in all of them, mashing up some code snippets you found elsewhere in order to create an application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your AOP method need to cast the result to something in order to get the code value it needs to log. That something must be known in advance, since you can't use type parameters in annotations, and therefore can't pass it to AOP methods. This means that all methods you access in AOP must come from a known interface, like this:

```
public interface LogCodeProvider {
    String getLogCode();
}

public class CaseOutlineHeader implements LogCodeProvider {
    @Override
    public String getLogCode() {
        return "My Code";
    }
}
```

And then in your AOP method you can do like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ResponseEntity<LogCodeProvider> returnValue = ResponseEntity<LogCodeProvider>) result;

result = etisLog.trasactionDetail().toString()+" "+returnValue.getBody().getLogCode();
```

In my example I have implemented special method getLogCode() which returns a string, so each class can decide exactly what to output.

It does however look confusing to reuse the result variable to store the value returned from `etisLog.trasactionDetail()`.

Answer (score 0):

Below sample code  ,

```
   ResponseEntity<?> anyRandomMethod(){
    if(any condition){
      return new ResponseEntity<Animal>(new Animal(), httpstatus.OK);
    }else{
      return new ResponseEntity<SpaceShip>(new SpaceShip(), httpstatus.OK);
    }

    }
```